# Function hanging on @Variable input, but not with hard coded integer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Very odd problem.  This function has randomly started hanging and timing out when I call it like this:

```
DECLARE @persId int 
SET @persId = 336

SELECT  * FROM  [CIDER].[dbo].[SMAN_ACL_getPermissions]   (
  null
  ,@persId
  ,1
  ,null)
GO
```

But returns super quick when I call it like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM  [CIDER].[dbo].[SMAN_ACL_getPermissions]   (
  null
  ,336
  ,1
  ,null)
GO
```

Could someone please highlight the difference between these two me?  It's making debugging very hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable could be a null value, whereas the static value definitely is not.  This can lead to different execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

You could be falling prey to parameter sniffing.  Take a look at the execution plan for the one that isn't performing well. In the plan XML, you'll see two values in the ParameterList tag: ParameterCompiledValue and ParameterRuntimeValue that are self-explanatory. If the data distribution is wildly different for the two, you could be getting a sub-optimal plan for your runtime value. You could try adding a "with (recompile)" to the statement that is running slow within your function and see if it helps